# Kafka Connect Elasticsearch - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to run the [kafka-connect-elasticsearch](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch) plugin from Confluent in order to stream topics from Kafka (**V0.11.0.1**) directly into Elasticsearch (without putting Logstash in between).

I build the connector using Maven -

```
$ cd kafka-connect-elasticsearch
$ mvn clean package
```

I then created the require configuration file -

```
name=es-cluster-lab
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=filebeats-test
topic.index.map=filebeats-test:kafka_test_index
key.ignore=true
schema-ignore=true
connection.url=http://elastic:9200
type.name=log
```

As per the new Kafka Classpath Isolation spec, I also added the following line to my `connect-standalone.properties` file -

```
plugin.path=/home/kafka/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-3.3.0/target/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-3.3.0-development/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/
```

I go to run the script ...

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/elasticsearch-connect.properties
```

... and receive the below error.

```
[2017-09-14 16:08:26,599] INFO Loading plugin from: /home/kafka/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-3.3.0/target/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-3.3.0-development/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:176)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:380)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:221)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:198)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:150)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:47)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:68)
```

I also tried to move the JAR files into the `/app/kafka/libs directory` (default CLASSPATH) and even tried to create a subdirectory `/app/kafka/libs/connect_libs` and add that manually to my CLASSPATH environment variable.

Not sure what my next step is besides putting Logstash between Kafka and Elastic.

Comment: Late Comment: Rather than put Kafka Connect in `home/kafka`, it would be better to move the build package folder into the actual Kafka installation folder

Answer (score 0):

try to change the guava version to 20 before you build it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the star **'*'** at the end of the path of the plugin path.

```
plugin.path=/home/kafka/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-3.3.0/target/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-3.3.0-development/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/*
```

Comment: That property needs to be a directory, not a glob pattern